# PXE network install without DHCP

Tags: networking, installation, centos, dhcp

I have a corporate network already working with DHCP based leases. So Can't use my own DHCP

I have a requirement to 
1) install linux based systems using Kickstart + network installation server on a centos-7 server

I can't use a DHCP while all the guides on the internet are saying to use the DHCP for network installation..

I can't use a USB for installation ... I have to do is select the PXE boot for installation of linux boxes..

Can someone please guide me how I can do a PXE boot without setting up the DHCP on network installation server running on centos. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use something called `proxyDHCP` + your already in place DHCP server unaltered

Answer (score 1):

PXE do require DHCP.

PXE can run from a proxyDHCP server - which only provides the boot options needed, and does not give IP leases to any client.

The most common service for proxyDHCP under Linux is probably dnsmasq, the sample config file mentions most of what you need, My own experience is with iPXE and as a minimal config for that you could use https://ipxe.org/appnote/proxydhcp

If you have static IP assignment, and DHCP is not allowed, then using something like iPXE on USB could be an alternate option, (of course requires that USB is allowed, or an CD or similar)